# Why does swift not work on my ubuntu?

Tags: gnome-terminal, snap, shared-library

I am trying to install swift on linux, I followed the instructions on swift.org on how to install swift, but when I try to check the version via following command `swift --version`, i get this error message: `/snap/swift/5/bin/swift: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`

Of course I was looking for a solution but I could'nt figure out what the problem for me is. with the command `apt-cache policy libatomic1` I checked if it was installed on my OS, this is what I get: `libatomic1:
  Installed: 8.2.0-7ubuntu1
  Candidate: 8.2.0-7ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 8.2.0-7ubuntu1 500
        500 http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

so where is the problem?

Comment: `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32` looks like you have installed a 32 bit application without having the necessary 32 bit support libraries. Either install a 64 bit version of the app, or go through the documentation to work out how to install the needed 32 bit architecture support.

Comment: how do i install the 64bit version and remove the 32bit version?

Comment: I don't know - how did you install it? The packages on swift.org seems to be tar-archives, but your error messages indicate a snap package. Try to see if swift has a forum, hat can help.

Comment: Do you know how to uninstall or remove the current packages and files ? I downloaded the RELEASE package for ubuntu 18.04 from their homepage